# Como uso o método "Math.Max" no C# sem precisar criar um monte de variáveis?

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, matemática

Estou tentando resolver um exercício que é assim:

> Faça um algoritmo que leia a altura e a matricula de dez aluno. Mostre a matricula do aluno mais alto e do aluno mais baixo

E meu código no momento está assim:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Altura dos Alunos");
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Qual a sua altura: ");
            double altura = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.WriteLine("Qual sua matrícula? Ex: 1234");
            int matricula = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double altura2 = 0;
            Math.Max( altura, altura2 );
            altura2 = altura;
        }
```

Como que eu uso o método `Math.Max()` para pegar a maior altura e mostrá-la depois sem que eu precise criar 10 variáveis?

Comment: primeiro você precisa ter onde armazenar os dez alunos...

Comment: Então eu terei que criar 10 variáveis mesmo para armazenar a altura e depois usar o Math.Max?

Comment: é mais provável que este seja um exercício utilizando arrays, logo, você declara apenas um array com 10 posições

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De fato isso está bem confuso. primeiro deve declarar a variável que controlará a altura máxima antes de entrar no laço, ela deve ser inicializada com uma valor abaixo do permitido.

Dentro você fará a comparação e atualizará a altura máxima com a máxima entre a anterior e a digitada. Note que fiz a conversão do jeito certo para não dar erro quando a digitação é equivocada. Se a digitação não passar no teste, ele volta 1 no laço exigindo uma digitação nova daquele elemento, esperando agora corretamente.

No final do laço o que sobre na variável de controle é a altura máxima.

Dei um nome mais significativo na variável de controle. Tirei o que não era relevante.

Quer menos variáveis que isso? Não tem jeito. É possível eliminar a variável `altura` se abrir mão da verificação se a digitação está certa. É possível abrir mão de `i` se repetir o pedido 10 vezes em vez de fazer um laço.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var maxAltura = -1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WriteLine("Qual a sua altura: ");
            double altura;
            if (double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out altura) && altura > 0) maxAltura = Max(maxAltura, altura);
            else i--;
        }
        WriteLine(maxAltura);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1tkGYt). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h1lJIG). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Max.cs).